# What can cause the biuret test to produce an orange colored solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

What can cause the biuret test to produce an orange colored solution?

I did the biuret test to a few number of foods in a school lab assignment. The test with tofu turned orange. I wonder why, since the biuret test is supposed to give violet as positive. I tried looking it up on google with no success.

An explanation I came up with is this: during my search, I found out the composition of the biuret and Fehling reagent is quite similar ([Fehling reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehling%27s_solution) and [biuret test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biuret_test)). Maybe the orange result has something to do with this similarity, as the Fehling test gives orange as the positive result. But the thing is, the Fehling test I did on the tofu showed a negative result. At first, I suspect I took the test tube with Fehling for the biuret. But this is not the case since my classmates got the same orange result with the biuret.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be formatted using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem with Biuret Test in this case is the Lowry Assay which get the same principe as Biuret Test. My hypothesis comes from my stability testing. By 2 weeks of stability testing, the result giving me orange colours which i think it is either the hyaluronic acid that is contained in the sample interfere the result or the protein is degraded and the negative result shows orange colour